# GameCenter Submits Score but Returns Error in iOS

Tags: ios, game-center

I have followed the tutorial on http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-sdk-game-center-achievements-and-leaderboards-part-1/ and managed to get everything work.. The thing is when I submit a score, the keeps saying "Missing Method". How can I fix this problem? Thanks..

```
- (void) callDelegate: (SEL) selector withArg: (id) arg error: (NSError*) err
{
    assert([NSThread isMainThread]);
    if([delegate respondsToSelector: selector])
    {
        if(arg != NULL)
        {
            [delegate performSelector: selector withObject: arg withObject: err];
        }
        else
        {
            [delegate performSelector: selector withObject: err];
        }
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Missed Method");
    }
}
```

PS: [code](https://mobiletuts.s3.amazonaws.com/iOS-SDK_Game-Center/GameCenter-ProjectCode.zip)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the selector and what is the delegate?

If "Missed Method" is printed, it means that the method the selector is describing, is not implemented on the delegate object.

Maybe you are passing an incorrect selector or maybe the delegate object is not set or not implemented entirely?

**Edit based on comments below:**
It appears you did not implement the optional methods of the GameCenterManagerDelegate protocol on your MainViewControllerClass, while it is set as the delegate of your GameCenterManager. This is ok, but if you want to get rid of the "Missing method" log message, you should make sure your MainViewControllerClass implements the entire protocol:

```
@protocol GameCenterManagerDelegate <NSObject>
@optional
- (void) processGameCenterAuth: (NSError*) error;
- (void) scoreReported: (NSError*) error;
- (void) reloadScoresComplete: (GKLeaderboard*) leaderBoard error: (NSError*) error;
- (void) achievementSubmitted: (GKAchievement*) ach error:(NSError*) error;
- (void) achievementResetResult: (NSError*) error;
- (void) mappedPlayerIDToPlayer: (GKPlayer*) player error: (NSError*) error;
@end
```

For the case you are describing, it is the "- (void) scoreReported: (NSError*) error;" that is missing. The GameCenterManager submits all the scores and once it has done so, it tries to call the scoreReported callback on its delegate. It then notices the method is not present on its delegate and prints out "Missing Method".
If you do not want to do anything once a score has been reported, you can just leave this as is though.

Comment: original code is here.. it does the same thing.. https://mobiletuts.s3.amazonaws.com/iOS-SDK_Game-Center/GameCenter-ProjectCode.zip

Comment: Did you set your delegate on the GameCenterManager class, and did you implement the GameCenterManagerDelegate callbacks in your own code?

Comment: No.. I didn't touch the GameCenterManager class. How can I do that?

Comment: `NSLog(@"selector: %@ arr: %@ and err: %@", NSStringFromSelector(selector), arg, err);
    NSLog(@"delegate: %@", delegate);` gives me selector: scoreReported: arr: (null) and err: (null)
delegate: <MainViewController: 0xb141f20>

Comment: Ok, so is the "- (void) scoreReported: (NSError*) error;" method implemented on your MainViewController class?